# Ruby - Parse out a list of locations cities, then take that list of cities and parse out the locations of each one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I'm currently trying to create a directory page for my business locations. I can easily just list out all locations, but would much rather list out the states of the locations, then underneath list out the location cities in that state. Then finally underneath the state, list out the location names.

I'm currently getting all locations with the line below.

```
@locations = @brand.locations.all
```

Then I create two blank arrays for states and cities.

```
@states = []
@cities = []
```

Once I've created the arrays I want to iterate through the locations to append the states and cities to their appropriate arrays.

```
@locations.each do |location|
  @states << location.state
  @cities << location.city
end
```

How could I append the locations to their appropriate cities in the city array? I was considering using a hash within the @cities array, but have gotten stuck from there. Sorry if this seems like a basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

`Hash[@locations.all.group_by(&:state).map{|k,v| [k, v.group_by(&:city)]}]`

This generates something like:

```
{
  "NY": {
    "Schenectady": [ ... locations in schenectady new york ... ],
    "Manhattan": [ ... locations in manhattan new york ...]
  },
  "TX": {
    "Austin": [ ... locations in austin texas ... ]
  }
}
```

Comment: was busy writing an inferior answer